# me lanza un error al crear objetos del tipo ImageView en javafx

Tags: java, javafx, maven

Estoy intentado mostrar una imagen en el stage de java con javafx, sin embargo el solo crear  el objeto imagen view incluso aun sin agregarlo a la escene me lanza error, en el siguiente codigo esta lo que estoy intentado compilar y me sale error.

El enunciado del error dice así:

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project problemImg: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        Image im = new Image("/1.png");
        ImageView imgUser = new ImageView(im);
        root.getChildren().add(imgUser);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setTitle("JavaFX and Maven");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

cabe destacar que en el código no tengo ninguna alerta

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciona esto:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
    public class Main extends Application {
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            primaryStage.setTitle("ImageVies"); 
            FileInputStream input=null;
            try {
                input=new FileInputStream("main/resources/ok.png");
                Image image=new Image(input);
                ImageView imageView=new ImageView(image);   
                HBox vBox=new HBox(imageView);
                Scene scene=new Scene(vBox,400,100);
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

Yo agregue la carpeta `main/resources` como `Source Folder` y si te das cuenta no inicia con `/`. Ademas primero leo el archivo con `FileInputStream` y no directo desde `Image`.

Comment: Si me funciona, sin embargo, el código de mi pregunta esta bien propuesto y me lanza un error, y es la duda que tengo, pareciera ser un error de configuración porque el solo hecho de crear el objeto ImageView me genera un error, aun y cuando no sea agregado al root.

Comment: Si no pones todo el código y el error esta difícil ayudar. No somos adivinos, solo dices me manda error, pero no has puesto el error.

Comment: ya edite mi pregunta, y la puse un poco mas completa, espero sea de utilidad para expresar mi problema

Comment: Según ahí, tu error no tiene nada que ver con `javafx`, es un error en maven, al parecer intentas usar un componente muy viejo, pero necesitamos ver el pom para saberlo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420561/what-is-mojo-in-maven